# Chrome extension to capture formdata and use this data to form fill in another tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a simple chrome extension so that when a form on a webpage in a specific website is populated and the user presses Submit then the data in the form is captured and then some of that data is injected into another form running on a different website.

I have no access to edit the code for either of the forms so a chrome extension seems to be the best way to do this from what I have read.

I would like to know if this is possible and how to go about it

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Thanks Jay - very helpful in terms of understanding the process and the flow.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), a [Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), and/or [Chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage)

You will need Content Scripts on both websites that have the forms. Use the [Manifest File](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) correctly to set up which websites to attach which Content Scripts to.

The first Content Script (the one reading the form being filled and submitted) will have to take the values of each form input, triggered by the submit button.

Then you will need to use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging) to send a message (containing all the form data) from that Content Script to your Background Page. The data can be held temporarily or saved into chrome.storage by the Background Page.

Then the second form's Content Script also uses Message Passing to request the data from Background Page, which is delivered from temporary holding or retrieved from chrome.storage then sent.

And finally the second Content Script modifies its website's form to fill in the values.